# Normalise Api response with NgRX Entity

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, rxjs, ngrx

Is it possible to take nested JSON api response and normalize it with NgRx Entity library?
If I have an object that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "My first post!",
        "author": {
            "id": "123",
            "name": "Paul"
        },
        "comments": [
            {
                "id": "249",
                "content": "Nice post!",
                "commenter": {
                    "id": "245",
                    "name": "Jane"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "250",
                "content": "Thanks!",
                "commenter": {
                    "id": "123",
                    "name": "Paul"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "This other post",
        "author": {
            "id": "123",
            "name": "Paul"
        },
        "comments": [
            {
                "id": "251",
                "content": "Your other post was nicer",
                "commenter": {
                    "id": "245",
                    "name": "Jane"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "252",
                "content": "I am a spammer!",
                "commenter": {
                    "id": "246",
                    "name": "Spambot5000"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to make it as flat as possible with NgRx Entity, is this possible and if so how?

I have tried using the normalizr library and it can flatten out the object quite nicely but it doesn't fit well with NgRx helper functions , such as createReducers() and createActions().

Anyone got any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `@ngrx/entity` does not provide normalize utilities.
It contains the CRUD actions to store and read a collection to the store.

Comment: So to achieve what I want I should use normalizr library and normalize the the api response and then store the output from that into seperate entitites?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to do it manually or use a library like normilizr

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help! Marking this as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Sure

You likely have an effect anywhere which looks like the one from the official doc (https://ngrx.io/guide/effects):

```
loadMovies$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType('[Movies Page] Load Movies'),
    mergeMap(() => this.moviesService.getAll()
      .pipe(
        // map -> flat your response here
        map(movies => ({ type: '[Movies API] Movies Loaded Success', payload: movies })),
        catchError(() => EMPTY)
      ))
    )
  );
```

You can simply put another map beforehand which flattens the movies array. You could use lodash functions to do so.

Comment: No need to use lodash

Comment: This doesn’t create seperate entities for the flattened object though...